# List Foreach Loop C#

Tags: c#, list, foreach

The Code I Generated

```
TrendyolProductAddlist model = new TrendyolProductAddlist
            {
                items = new List<ProductAdditems>
                {
                new ProductAdditems
                {
                    barcode=entegrasyon_barkod,
                    title=urun_baslik,
                    productMainId=stok_kodu,
                    brandId=trendyol_marka_id,
                    categoryId=trendyol_kategori_id,
                    quantity=stok,
                    stockCode=stok_kodu,
                    dimensionalWeight=desi,
                    description=urun_aciklama,
                    currencyType=para_birimi,
                    listPrice=Convert.ToDecimal(trendyol_psf),
                    salePrice=Convert.ToDecimal(trendyol_price),
                    vatRate = urun_kdv,
                    cargoCompanyId=kargo_id,
                     images = new List<Productimagelist>
                     {
                         new Productimagelist { url = resim1 }
                     } ,
                     attributes = new List<Productattributeslist>
                     {
                         new Productattributeslist { attributeId=renk_id, customAttributeValue= renk },
                         new Productattributeslist { attributeId=cinsiyet_id, attributeValueId= cinsiyet_valueid },
                         new Productattributeslist { attributeId = yasgrubu_id, attributeValueId = yasgrubu_valueid }

                     }
                }
                }
            };
```

Class :

```
  public string attributeId { get; set; }
        public string attributeValueId { get; set; }
        public string customAttributeValue { get; set; }
```

How can I get the code like this?
I want to add a new list as many rows in dgw

```
attributes = new List<Productattributeslist>
{
   foreach (DataGridViewRow dgwRow in dataGridView1.Row)
  {
     new Productattributeslist { attributeId = dgwRow.Cells[0].Value , customAttributeValue = dgwRow.Cells[1].Value },
  }
}
```

how many lines in the dgw i want to use sending a attributess will happen, but it will not be possible to loop it are visible

Comment: Are you asking how to add items to a list? Take a look at the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-5.0) method

Comment: I voted to close, because the first comment started with "Are you asking how ...."

Comment: Also: "How can I get the code like this?"  Answer: Copy/paste ??   Please add more info on what you are trying to do!

Comment: No, create a new 'Productattributeslist' for each line I want to make.

Comment: your first code snippet is used for shorthand, declarative initialization of a known set; the second is programmatically determined. If you're doing code generation, the concept would be to generate .cs file for your project where you're ultimately writing\generating strings\text content of that file.  You could use a T4 template for such a matter.   It's a little unclear whether that is your intention, and certainly a more complex implementation then doing a helper method that returns an initialized `List<Productattributeslist>` using `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.

Comment: i'm sorry to edit my entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern and issue seems to be support for Looping Control Flow as it relates to [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers); The syntax doesn't seem to support Looping inline (that would then expand into the object initializer), but you can achieve the result by invocations during right-hand assignment.

In the snippet you provided, your objective is to generate an initialized `List<Productattributeslist>` instance based on the collection of `DataGridViewRow` in `dataGridView1.Row`.

#### Calling Helper function

```
    attributes = GenerateProductAttributesList(dataGridView1.Rows)

#region "Helper Functions" // Can be defined as private static, or local .. depends on scope and testability you have in mind

List<Productattributeslist> GenerateProductAttributesList(DataGridViewRowCollection dgwRows) {
    var resultList = new List<Productattributeslist>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgwRow in dgwRows)
    {
        resultList.Add(SelectProductAttributesListItem(dgwRow));
    }
    return resultList;
} 

Productattributeslist SelectProductAttributesListItem(DataGridViewRow dgvwRow) => new Productattributeslist() 
{
     attributeId = dgvwRow.Cells[0].Value,
     customAttributeValue = dgvwRow.Cells[1].Value 
};
#endregion
```

#### Using Linq (`using System.Linq;` at top)

```
    attributes = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select((dgvwRow) => new Productattributeslist() 
    {
        attributeId = dgvwRow.Cells[0].Value,
        customAttributeValue = dgvwRow.Cells[1].Value 
    }).ToList()
```

The above Linq sample uses an anonymous delegate that's defined and passed to `.Select` method.  It's usually the way to go for simple mappings, but you might consider declaring a method to pass.

#### Combination of using Linq and passing a Helper Function to as delegate.

```
    attributes = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(SelectProductAttributesListItem).ToList()


#region "Helper Function"
Productattributeslist SelectProductAttributesListItem(DataGridViewRow dgvwRow) => new Productattributeslist() 
{
     attributeId = dgvwRow.Cells[0].Value,
     customAttributeValue = dgvwRow.Cells[1].Value 
};
#endregion
```

Comment: Thanks for being smooth and understandable, all my problems have been solved my friend